# How to save specific strings in a file to variables in C

Tags: c, file, c-strings

So if for example I have a file with the following content:

```
STUDENTS: Three
NAME 1: Andy
NAME 2: Becky
NAME 3: Chris
TYPE: Undergrads
```

I would like to extract the names of the students into an array.

I have tried to implement this using fscanf, for instance this works and I can save "Three" to student struct:

`fscanf(fptr, "STUDENTS: %s\n", student.count);`

So I've tried some variations of this (where count is the number of lines in the file), but the names array remains empty:

```
int *num = NULL;
*num = 1;
int j;
for (j=0; j<count; j++) {
   if (j != 0 && j != count-1) {
       fscanf(fptr, "NAME %d: %s\n", num, student.names[j]);
       *num+=1;
   }
}
```

Is there a better method than fscanf, for example fseek() which I am not really familiar with.  Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

edit:

```
struct Students {

  char *name;
  char *type;
  char *connections[6];

};

struct Students student;
```

Comment: please walk this code with a debugger. otherwise you will never learn how to code. Show us all your declarations. Also, you should test the code without a file, hard code some test data in variables and test with that.

Comment: Please include the declaration of `student`. Also, why did you make `num` pointer to int rather than just int?

Comment: So if I remove the file, then I completely change the string manipulation situation from a file that I am trying to accomplish.  I can easily populate the array by hard-coding.  I will add the Student struct, although again I'm not sure why that would be necessary for this particular question (I could be wrong though).  The reason I made num pointer to int is that fscanf didn't seem to accept an int.

Comment: So,`num` should ideally be an int and then you should pass `&num` to `fscanf`. The declaration of student is important so that we can see whether or not your code to fscanf names into it will work or not (and it won't work, notwithstanding the name/names typo).

Answer (score 2):

The `scanf` family of functions isn't great for scanning lines that have variable formats.  In this case a reasonable approach is to first scan the input line as a tag and string value separated by a colon.

```
char tag[MAX_TAG_SIZE], value[MAX_VALUE_SIZE];
if (fscanf(f, "%[^:]: %s ", tag, value) != 2) error("bad line format");
```

This format string gets any series of characters other than `:` into `tag`. Then it skips a `:` followed by whitespace. Then it gets a non-whitespace word into `value` followed by skipping whitespace (including newlines).  The last bit gets the input ready to scan the next tag, which is important. The biggest mistake new C programmers make with `scanf` is forgetting to deal correctly whitespace in the input stream.

Now you can inspect the tag to see what to do next:

```
if (strcmp("STUDENTS", tag) == 0) {
   ... Handle students value
} else if(strcmp("TYPE", tag) == 0) {
   ... Handle type value
} else if (strncmp("NAME", tag, 4) == 0) {
    if (sscanf(tag + 4, "%d", &name_number) != 1) error("bad name number");
    ... Handle name_number and value
} else error("unexpected tag");
```